# SWIFT: Get high priority for my app to use internet data

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-data

I have data intensive app that heavily relies on web services. iOS does not let it use data where as at the same time other applications(like youtube) can get high data volume.

The same app works flawlessly on android.

How can I programmatically get high priority for my app for internet data usage?
I'm using Swift 2.3.

Comment: you'll need to post code to get help.

Comment: @johnelemans thanks for the comment, but I am not sure what part of code... Its a 100+ ViewControllers... 
Mainly, I just want to know how to get high priority from iOS for data usage, like setting something in appdelegate, or plist, or any other configuration...

Comment: Calling webservice isn't data intensive so ios should allow it. it won't throttle it unless you are doing too much work when app is in background and you have not set the required background permissions. Does it not allow you to connect even when app is open?

Comment: @kapsym  ...Makes sense... I will try to set configuration and isDiscretionary to true.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that you have to set a higher timoutIntervall for the request. I had a similar problem, where the request took to long and could not finished loading the data. I found out that the request is by default set to 60 seconds or something like this.

So try to set

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: searchURL, cachePolicy: NSMutableURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 300)
```

to a higher value like 300.

So it is not the amount of data, it is because of time it takes to download it.

Maybe this will help.

Comment: . I am already using a high value as time out value. If I set it more than this, than application will not be user friendly. I will try to set configuration and isDiscretionary to true.